# Weird cartoon show: characters get trapped in a game show hosted by an alien, can only escape if they win the show

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

There's this cartoon show and in one episode they get trapped in a game show. The host is some weird alien that stands on a floating disk. The only way out is if they win the show.

Comment: Possibly [this](https://jimmyneutron.fandom.com/wiki/Win_Lose_and_Kaboom!)? But without more detail in your question, it's really hard to tell.

Comment: hey kevin, its not this but thanks

Comment: Please provide [more information](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/36526) to help us figure out what you're thinking of. Otherwise, this will just turn into a guessing game.

Comment: You can post that as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Honorable mention for [*The Killing Game Show*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Killing_Game_Show).

Answer (score 4):

**As this question's asker's account was deleted so they will not self-answer, I am taking the answer they said that [they found](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/214065/4) and turning it into a answer.**

This is "The Feud!", episode 54 of *Voltron: Legendary Defender*, and the 4th episode of season seven. It was released on August 10, 2018.

A brief summary that matches the question:

> The Paladins find themselves on a bizarre game show called "Garfle Warfle Snick!" hosted by an alien called Bob. They have to amass enough points to win their freedom.
>   
> <sub>[source](https://voltron.fandom.com/wiki/The_Feud!#Plot_Summary)</sub>

Bob, the host, sits on a sort of disc-like floating thing.

[image: A green alien with antennae sitting in some sort of floating machine with a microphone]